# FPDI slightly crops my imported PDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I am using FPDI and FPDF and when I import my pdf which has a full-sized, good-looking design, for some reason the generated pdf that I save in a folder is slightly modified in size, a bit smaller / cropped both at the bottom and on the right/left sides. How can I import the PDF as is? With the exact same size as the original? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

require_once('FPDF/fpdf.php');
require_once('FPDI/src/autoload.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new Fpdi();

$pdf->setSourceFile('file.pdf');
$tplidx = $pdf->importPage(1);

$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetXY(5, 5);
$pdf->Write(8, 'This is an example of inputted text.');

$filename="test8.pdf";
$pdf->Output($filename, 'F');

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good issue to show that FPDI does not modify a PDF but let you import page into a reusable structure.

You defined no page size in the constructor nor in the addPage() call, so your resulting page size is [A4](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/__construct.htm) (default size).

If you import a page in e.g. letter format this imported page will not fit onto the A4 page - sure.

There are some solutions for this:

A: Get the size of the imported page and call AddPage() with this parameter:

```
$pageId = $this->ImportPage($pageNo);
$s = $this->getTemplatesize($pageId);
$this->AddPage($s['orientation'], $s);
$this->useTemplate($pageId);
```

B: Set the $adjustPageSize parameter of the [useImportedPage()](https://manuals.setasign.com/api-reference/fpdi2/c/setasign.Fpdi.Fpdi#method_useImportedPage) / [useTemplate()](https://manuals.setasign.com/api-reference/fpdi2/c/setasign.Fpdi.Fpdi#method_useTemplate) method to true:

```
$this->AddPage();
$pageId = $this->ImportPage($pageNo);
$this->useTemplate($pageId, ['adjustPageSize' => true]);
```

I would suggest solution A because it's straight forward.